# Tag 'throttling' vs. 'rate-limiting'

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I draw your attention to the [throttling](/questions/tagged/throttling) and [rate-limiting](/questions/tagged/rate-limiting) tags here on Meta Stack Exchange.

The former is only on a few questions, and there is no usage guidance or tag wiki. From what I can see, the questions tagged thus are asking about Stack Exchange rate limits (and at least one question is tagged with both).

It seems to me that [throttling](/questions/tagged/throttling) should be a synonym of [rate-limiting](/questions/tagged/rate-limiting). I'd suggest just removing the tag from those few questions, but it's a fairly common term, and I expect that it will be re-created in relatively short order.

If "throttling" is purely for the Stack Exchange API, then perhaps it should be [api-throttling](/questions/tagged/api-throttling), but that seems to me to be a distinction without a difference.

Comment: Well rate-limiting and API throttling are different things. There are only a handful of questions so I'd say retag the incorrectly tagged [tag:throttling] questions and replace (as you said) [tag:throttling] with [tag:api-throttling]

Comment: Saying that, the [API docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) call it "rate limiting" in the sidebar. There's currently only 1 [tag:throttling] question explicitly asking about the API (and one indirectly) so maybe there doesn't need to be a distinction.

Comment: Not sure I understand why the Close vote with reason "pertains to only a specific site". It pertains to _this_ site, Meta Stack Exchange. I don't know what other site you think I might be talking about.

Comment: Yeh the CV makes no sense at all (I voted to leave open btw) :/

Comment: @ale: Someone might be thinking that all API questions should be asked on StackApps, and that questions about those questions don't fit here accordingly. Both are wrong, but that's at least a vaguely plausible line of reasoning.